# why isn't col- working when col-sm and col-md,etc work just fine?

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

On this page, http://phglass.cl/tienda/vista/carrito.php
(after adding a product)
I'm using the customizable bootstrap from this page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/
where I've only selected "grid system"
anything with col-sm-2 or higher works but when I try col-2 it only comes out as full width, what can I do to fix it?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-2">
```

**Solved: for bootstrap 3 I have to use col-xs-2 instead of col-2**

Comment: What does your inspect window show as far as CSS that might be overriding bootstrap?

Comment: there's div {display:block} ?

Comment: @IsabelNava We will need more information here to help you out...can you replicate the issue with  a jsfiddle? or show us what the console looks like.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnjuc5qt/
something like this

Comment: there is no col-2 in boostrap3, you are probably looking for `col-xs-2`

Comment: thats the one, i just saw it, thank you... so much struggle x.x

Answer (score 0):

First, try using Boostrap 4

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-md-8">.col-12 .col-md-8</div>
   <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thats an example from [Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/). Rember you need to import the library

Comment: I dont want to use all of the library, only the grid